# Why does kill -9 0 on a mac simply kill the bash shell?

Tags: macos

I'm trying to see what happens when I try to kill the `kernel_task` process. Since `kill -9 pid` is the command to force quit a process, and `kernel_task`'s pid is 0, I simply ran `kill -9 0`.

Instead of getting `Permission Denied` or a `Operation not permitted` when killing a root process, you simply get this:

```
Last login: Thu Jun 18 16:55:10 on ttys005
MacBook-Air:~ james$ kill -9 0

[Process completed]
```

... which is weird because trying to kill `launchd` (one level below `kernel_task`) gives you this:

```
-bash: kill: (1) - Operation not permitted
```

and all other root processes.

Why the heck does it just terminate the process that called the command, instead of sending `Operation not permitted`, like all the other root processes?

Bonus points if you can tell me the answer to this question:
If you create a script that tries to kill `kernel_task` (and ignores `SIGTERM`), running it will output `Killed: 9` and return to bash. Why does it put that into stdout when it kills it? Why not something more descriptive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> and `kernel_task`'s pid is 0

They probably use the PID 0, because it is a reserved PID and as such you cannot send signals to the process.

> I simply ran `kill -9 0`.

The *nix command `kill` is more or less a direct front-end for [the `kill` system call](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/kill.2.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/2/kill). From the documentation of the system call:

```
If pid is zero:
      Sig is sent to all processes whose group ID is equal to the process group ID of the sender, and
      for which the process has permission; this is a variant of killpg(2).
```

In other words, in your case, `kill -9 0` is just a fancy way to send the (fatal) signal to itself. ([More about process groups.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_group))

> Why the heck does it just terminate the process that called the command

The `kill` (unless you have tweaked the shell settings) is a built-in shell command. In other words, the shell calls the `kill` syscall and that causes it to kill itself.

Try the same but with the external `kill` command, e.g. `/bin/kill -9 0`. In that case only the `/bin/kill` would be killed.

Comment: What does IOW mean?

Comment: IOW - in other words

Comment: So in other words, 0 is a reserved pid just for kernel_task, but it also means "yourself", just like the IP address 127.0.0.1 means yourself.

Comment: Something like this. PID 0 in case of the `kill` pointing to process group is part of the POSIX interface of the `kill`. Under Mac OS X, `kernel_task` having PID 0 is a detail of realization of the POSIX. That seemingly conflicts with the POSIX, but in practice it doesn't, since POSIX doesn't allow PID 0 being used by a real process.